# jQuery selector depending on children

Tags: jquery-selectors

I have an HTML form consisting of some text-inputs. I'm using jqTransform to prettify them. Now I want to add two buttons that will add and remove text-input dynamically.

Adding is easy:
  $('#container').append('');
  $('input[name=foo]:last-child').jqTransInputText();

But removing is tricky:
  $('WHAT-TO-SELECT').remove();

I can't do "input[name=foo]:last-child" since it's already wrapped (some divs) by jqTransform. To put this question in another way: How do I select based on "who has child of type input with 'foo' as its name"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I closed the issue not by giving solution to the problem, instead I enclose the input tag with div thus eliminating the problem. So to remove the input tag, I simply remove the div. Thanks anyway guys!

Answer (score 1):

You might try selecting the `input with 'foo' as its name` and grabbing it's parent.

`$('input[name=foo]').closest('.parentSelector').remove();`

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure what you mean. but it looks like you could be doing more work on it by just chaining..   ie..

```
$('input[name=foo]:last-child').jqTransInputText().remove();
```

I'm not sure if that's exactly what you are looking for..  if not, look into the [find function](http://api.jquery.com/find/) in jQuery.

Comment: Sorry..   more info on find.   Basically, find can either filter your current collection in the chain.  ie.. `$("p").find("span").css('color','red');`
will only change the colors of the paragraphs with spans contained in them.  You could also do this by `$('p span')`, but using find allows you to do things like `$('p').slideUp().find('span').css('color','red');`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[name=foo]').parent().remove();
```

Additionally the parent method can be supplied with an normal selector as well to only remove a specific parent.